# Change the position of UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

I am working on an iPad project and I want to handle both modes portrait and landscape views.

**When I go into landscape mode the `UIBarButtonItem` does not change position.** Is there a method to move this button and put it in the right side of the bar?

Portrait :

[image]

Landscape :

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **resolved** the problem like this :

In the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` method i wrote :

```
if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        //Change the position of the profil button
        [self changeProfilButtonOrientation];   
    }else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){

    }
```

And my `changeProfilButtonOrientation` method

```
-(void) changeProfilButtonOrientation{
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [self.toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace,profilButton, nil]];
}
```

**And it works :-)**

Answer (score 1):

I think present location setting is lick below:

[image: ss]

Under this setting **the length of left margin** is adopted to landscape mode. So you have to set **the length of right margin** and let the botton put right end of navigation bar.

You would better set the setting as below:

[image: ss]

You can edit these setting by **size inspector** (Please look on this by yourself).

I with this advice is help for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, there are no different between the 2 pictures XD...Can you update your answer please?